# document.getElementById().value does not work in form's hidden field asp.net web pages

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, razor

I created a simple website using ASP.NET Web Pages (using Razor markup). I have a form with two hidden fields: `latitude` and `longitude`. In my JS script I use HTML5 Geolocation API to get user's location expressed in degrees (latitude and longitude) and then try to assign these values to the two hidden fields in the form before sending them out to a server.

The problem is I use `getElementById().value` method to assign these value and it does not seem to work! I can print out the values in the same place in script using a simple `alert()` message so I'm pretty sure it's `getElementById().value` that doesn't work.

Here's code for my form:

```
<form  id="locationForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return getLocation()">
Search for cinema showings in my area<br />
<input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="latitude" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
</form>
```

And here's code for my script:

```
<script>
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");

    }
}
function showPosition(position) {

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    alert("lat is: " + lat);

    document.getElementById('latitude').value = position.coords.latitude;

    document.getElementById("longitude").value = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Comment: What is the symptom that's leading you to believe that it "doesn't work"? Have you tested your server (or whatever you're submitting to) to make sure it's not a problem with parsing the form data?

Comment: This script tag... where is placed? Are you getting any error in the console. If 'latitude' or 'longitude' do not exist, you should receive a 'can't invoke property value of null' or similar.

Comment: It doesn't pass any values to the server side. When I hard code it like value="000000", it passes these just fine.

Comment: @OscarPaz If the `alert` works it shouldn't be about the actual lookup of the latitude/longitude on the client.

Comment: script is placed at the end of <body> before </body> obviously. Using WebMatrix 3 and no errors.

Comment: I know, but maybe it's that you are calling `getElementById` when the DOM is not ready...

Comment: @OscarPaz How can that be possible given `getLocation` is called after the form is submitted?

Comment: Don't know if it affects the DOM, but I'm using  a layout page like that: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_layout.asp

Comment: You're right, @Chris. Anyway... how are you submitting the form, @roccopwner? In your code, the submit of the form is interrupted by you returning `undefined` from `getLocation()`. If you don't do anything else, then your data is never sent to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,I solved the problem although it can be considered a bit of a "hack".
I created a separate button that call the same getLocation function to change the values of latitude and longitude fields and submit the form using:

```
document.locationForm.submit();
```

Then on the load of the page I use jQuery to hide the submit button:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".submit").hide();
});
</script>
```

What I noticed is that the old script did change values of the hidden fields after all, just did not post them to the server. If anyone finds out what caused this to not work is welcome, but for now thanks for all the answers!

Comment: I think i found what was causing the issue, please check the updated answer... :)

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for my English ... my native language is Portuguese / Brazil.

I have the same problem. I had to check my codes in many browsers and Windows Versions.

document . GetElementById (HIDDENFormVariable) . value = 'string' does NOT run in ...

- IE 11 Windows 7:**Does not run**
- Mozila  Windows 7:  **Does not run**
- Chrome 37.0.2062.124 Vista Business: **Does not run**
- Chrome 38.0.2125  Windows 7:  **Does not run**
- Chrome 38.0.2125  Windows XP:  **Does not run**
- IE 9 Windows Vista Business: Does run
- IE 7 Windows XP:  Does run

BUT ..

In Windows Explorer 11, if you change in `[Tools] > [Compatibility View Settings]` and include your site at the list it will run Ok in Windows 7 with IE 11. Then is not a bug, but it was changed by IE. Chrome do not accept the change - hidden input in any of Windows or old version that I have checked.

**I SOLVED it from another way**

Where I had
`<input type="HIDDEN">`

I changed to

`<DIV STYLE="visibility:hidden">  <input type="TEXT">  </DIV>`

Text inputs can be changed by javascript and inside the `DIV` they do not need to be showed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) runs asynchronously. So, the form submission handler will not wait for the `geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` method to finish and execute it's success callback - where you are assigning the values to input fields. Instead it continues execution i.e:

You have specified `onsubmit="return getLocation()"` in the inline event handler but you're not returning anything - hence the function will return `undefined` immediately and the `<form>` is submitted, regardless of the status of `geolocation` method.

---

You can solve this issue by preventing the form submission using `event.preventDefault()` and manually submitting the form inside the success callback of `getCurrentPosition()` as shown below:

HTML:

```
<form id="locationForm" method="post" action="">Search for cinema showings in my area
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
var form = document.getElementById("locationForm");
form.addEventListener("submit", getLocation);

function getLocation(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the form submission
    if (navigator.geolocation) 
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
     else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
};

function success(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude,
        long = position.coords.longitude;

    alert("lat is: " + lat + "long is: " + long);
    document.getElementById("latitude").value = lat;
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = long;
    form.submit(); // successfully set the values, submitting the form
}

function error(){
    alert("Unable to retrieve you location");
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/3ETQK/5/)

Comment: Didn't down vote, but I wanted to pass these values latitude and longitude to the server using form without displaying them, therefore used hidden fields. Thanks for answering though

Comment: i used textboxes to display that `getElementId()` is working, which is the title of your question.

Comment: how are you accessing the value in server side? you can't use javascript for accessing it @ server side. the javascript and the function is working fine as the fiddle shows.

Comment: using ifPost to get the values if true and display a form if false

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, the `onsubmit` is fired when the form is already being submitted.
Try calling the function through the submit button's `onclick`

Comment: I thought of this too, but his is using `return getLocation();`. `getLocation()` returns `undefined`, which is interpreted as false and so the form does not submit.

Comment: well, if I do something like this: document.getElementById("longitude").value = position.coords.longitude;

alert(document.getElementById("longitude").value); it prints the correct value! very odd

Answer (score -1):

OK I tried another approach.
Add a name to to your form, like `name="geoform"`

Now, in the `showPosition` function, change the last lines to:

```
document.geoform.latitude.value = position.coords.latitude;
document.geoform.longitude.value = position.coords.longitude;
```

Comment: Could it be a local problem? Here's your code with my changes   http://jsfiddle.net/g67D7/   and it works fine.